# Create a Dockerfile for a database with a restoring dump

Tags: dockerfile

I want to create a Dockerfile for the database. In this Dockerfile I want to add a dump and restore. Then I build an image, and everytime I run a container I will have the database restored

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM postgres:9.5.8

WORKDIR /home/

COPY my_dump.sql my_dump.sql

EXPOSE 5432 5432

RUN psql -f my_dump.sql postgres
```

Then I execute

```
$ docker build -t my_postgres_db .
```

I get

```
Step 5/5 : RUN psql -f my_dump.sql postgres
 ---> Running in 70f7b511cc7c
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
  Is the server running locally and accepting
  connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Comment: You might have to wait until postgres has completed startup

Comment: @KartikPrasad thank you, is that posible to do it inside the Dockerfile

Comment: You could try a Sleep for some time `RUN sleep 100`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice little script for doing this taken and altered from https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/

All you need to do is create the script

```
#!/bin/bash
# wait-for-postgres.sh

set -e

host="$1"
shift

until psql -h "$host" -U "postgres" -c '\q'; do
  >&2 echo "Postgres is unavailable - sleeping"
  sleep 1
done

>&2 echo "Postgres is up - you can execute commands now"
```

and then add this to the docker file

```
RUN /wait-for-postgres.sh host
```

Then run your commands after that